# IE8 button graphics

Tags: internet-explorer, graphics

Where does IE and windows store its graphics components, like the minimize, maximize, close buttons?  I want to use them in a custom project and have done all the usual searches but can't find the graphics store.

Thanks, R.

Comment: Ripping icons out of Windows/IE and using them in your product will most likely be illegal, as they are copyrighted.

Comment: Your probably right, i'll just make my own.

Comment: Hold on a second, this is a VS project, I was more interested in where they are stored, how to access them from code, I think 'ripping' them is slightly over the top.

Answer (score 1):

How and where they are stored depends on Windows version. I suppose that old windows stored min, max and close buttons icons as a TrueType font. However things certainly changed, XP introduced themes and Vista has Aero.
There is an old Win32 API function DrawFrameControl maybe it will help You.

I also remember that IE 6.0 stored resources in browseui.dll.